# How to wait interstitial ad with waiting dialog in flutter

Tags: flutter, dialog, admob, interstitial

[Here](https://support.google.com/admob/answer/6201362?hl=en) is an article which says you shouldn’t surprise users with interstitial ads.

I have code like this to delay an ad before it appears:

```
void _onLoading() {
showDialog(
    context: context,
    barrierDismissible: false,
    builder: (context) => AlertDialog(
          shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(32.0))),
          contentPadding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 10.0),
          content: Container(
            margin: const EdgeInsets.all(10.0),

              child: new Row(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                children: <Widget>[
                  new CircularProgressIndicator(),
                  SizedBox(width: 16.0),
                  new Text("Please wait.."),
                ],
              )),
        ));

new Future.delayed(new Duration(seconds: 3), () {
  Navigator.pop(context); //pop dialog
  createInterstitialAd()
    ..load()
    ..show();
});}
```

But that code just waits for 3 seconds and does not depend on interstitial ad when it appears. In that case, if after 3 second and if the connection is still slow, it will remain silent. How can I handle that until interstitial ad has really appeared.
Thanks.

Comment: The good idea is to load the interstitial ad when app opens and when you need to show the ad, check if the ad was loaded if yes, go ahead and show it else load it again and next time when an interesting event happens show it.

Comment: yes, thats a logic.. thanks
but, how about flutter code for handle it? or maybe Future delayed depends on interstitial ad appeared?

Comment: I'm sorry I didn't get you, why do you need `FutureDelayed`?

Comment: Yes, maybe some flutter code like that for wait until interstitial ad appear

Comment: I don't understand your need for using `Future.delayed()`, simply load ad when app starts and show it when you an interesting action occurs like user go to a new page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use this in my code :

```
InterstitialAd myInterstitialAd = InterstitialAd(
        adUnitId: <youradUnitId>,
        targetingInfo: MobileAdTargetingInfo(
          childDirected: true,
          nonPersonalizedAds: true,
        ),
        listener: (event) {
          if (event == MobileAdEvent.opened || event == MobileAdEvent.failedToLoad) {
            <go to another page>
          }
        });
```